# How to prove that $\vert f(z) \vert \geq 1 $ for all $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove this function has a modulus greater of equal than 1 : [Find all entire functions $f$ such that for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $|f(z)|\ge \frac{1}{|z|+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267941/find-all-entire-functions-f-such-that-for-all-z-in-mathbbc-fz-ge-f)

One answer says that “clearly” $\vert f(z) \vert \geq 1 $ for all $z$. But its not clear to me. How can I prove it? I am thinking a lot about this but I dont see it.

Comment: I would guess that answerer did the mental arithmetic with the inequalities too quickly. A-priori, It is not clear at all that $|f(z)|\geq 1$ for all $z$. The best bet is to follow the accepted answer: $\frac{1}{f}$ is an entire function which never vanishes, and which is bounded above by $1+|z|$. Hence (a modification of the proof of Liouville's theorem), $\frac{1}{f}$ is a polynomial (of degree $\leq 1$) and hence is constant (because you have degree $\leq 1$, this is obvious; more generally you can appeal to FTA). Hence, $f$ is constant (it is clear now that the constant is $\geq 1$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo How do I know that f(z) is never zero?

Comment: I said $\frac{1}{f}$ is never zero; this is extremely obvious simply because $f$ is complex-valued. The better question is why $\frac{1}{f}$ is entire, and the answer is that $f$ never vanishes (by the inequality) so its reciprocal is well-defined and entire.

Comment: If  $|f(z)|\ge \frac{1}{|z|+1}$ what happens if $\vert z\vert $ goes to infinite? We can say that $\vert f(z) \vert \geq 0 $, but how we can discard the equal to zero?

Comment: why are you taking limits? For each $z\in\Bbb{C}$, $|f(z)|\geq \frac{1}{|z|+1}>0$,  and hence $f(z)\neq 0$. This is literally what it means for $f$ to be nowhere vanishing. Note $\infty\notin\Bbb{C}$. If you're still not convinced, do the following simple exercise: sketch the function $\frac{1}{1+t}$ for $t\in [0,\infty)$. Does this graph ever intersect the horizontal axis? (you had better not say 'it intersects it at infinity':)

Comment: And if that is still not convincing, try a proof by contradiction. Suppose there is some $z\in\Bbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=0$. Then, $0=|f(z)|\geq \frac{1}{|z|+1}>0$, i.e $0>0$. How crazy is that?

Comment: @peek-a-boo My reasoning was based in the fact that, if we take an example from real functions , if we have $|f(x)|\geq \frac{1}{|x| +1}$, we can not rule out the posibility that f goes to zero as $\vert x\vert $goes to infinity  growths. Suppose this is true (f goes to zero). Then 1/f goes to infinity as x growths.

Comment: the **LIMIT** (if it exists) *could* be zero, yes. I'm not disputing that at all. But the inequality instantly tells us that the function itself is never equal to zero, and this is all that matters to us.

Comment: Because the function is entire, if the limit of $|f|$ exists at $\infty$ and is $< \infty$, the function has to be constant. If it diverges to $\infty$ at $\infty$, the function has to be a polynomial. All other entire functions have essential singularities at $\infty$. But this is of no consequence for what peek-a-boo has been saying, which follows from the properties of the function on $\Bbb C$, and again $\infty \notin \Bbb C$.